# logs from only some files showing up aws cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services

I configured aws cloudwatch log service on my linux instance. In the config file I set it to keep track of 3 log files:

```
[general]
state_file = /var/lib/awslogs/agent-state

[plugins]
cwlogs = cwlogs
[default]
region = us-west-1

[/var/log/cron]
file = /var/log/cron
log_group_name = /var/log/cron
log_stream_name = {instance_id}
datetime_format = %b %d %H:%M:%S

[/var/log/messages]
file = /var/log/messages
log_group_name = /var/log/messages
log_stream_name = {instance_id}
datetime_format = %b %d %H:%M:%S

[/var/log/test.log]
file = /var/log/test.log
log_group_name = /var/log/test.log
log_stream_name = {instance_id}
datetime_format = %b %d %H:%M:%S
```

However, in my console I'm only seeing logs showing up from messages. The permissions for the 3 files I'm trying to keep track of are `-rw-------`.

Does anybody know why this might be happening? I'm echoing test logs into each individual file and only the ones inserted into messages are showing up.

EDIT**: Here is my awslogs.log

```
2016-08-25 17:58:31,227 - cwlogs.push - INFO - 631 - MainThread - Missing or invalid value for use_gzip_http_content_encoding config. Defaulting to using gzip encoding.
2016-08-25 17:58:31,228 - cwlogs.push - INFO - 631 - MainThread - Using default logging configuration.
2016-08-25 17:58:31,234 - cwlogs.push.stream - INFO - 631 - Thread-1 - Starting publisher for [d4a8beb9b6b4535cac41dc75f252df59, /var/log/messages]
2016-08-25 17:58:31,234 - cwlogs.push.stream - INFO - 631 - Thread-1 - Starting reader for [d4a8beb9b6b4535cac41dc75f252df59, /var/log/messages]
2016-08-25 17:58:31,235 - cwlogs.push.reader - INFO - 631 - Thread-4 - Replay events end at 52578.
2016-08-25 17:58:31,235 - cwlogs.push.reader - INFO - 631 - Thread-4 - Start reading file from 52284.
2016-08-25 17:58:32,308 - cwlogs.push.publisher - WARNING - 631 - Thread-2 - Caught exception: An error occurred (DataAlreadyAcceptedException) when calling the PutLogEvents operation: The given batch of log events has already been accepted. The next batch can be sent with sequenceToken: 49561203985967314162297491311273568778757530964511949634
```

Comment: Check `/var/log/awslogs.log` for any errors logged by the CloudWatch Logs agent.

Comment: Hey Mark, thanks for the response. I updated my post to include my awslogs.log. Can you please take a look at it?

Comment: Mark, I noticed my logs are using the awslogs.conf, not the awscli.conf which I wrote the files in. The awsconf file already has a setup to get logs from the messages file

Answer (score 3):

It's possible your agent state file is corrupted because you kept making changes to the configuration. There are two ways to fix this:

- **Option 1:** Use a new name for your configuration block header.

  - That is, change `[/var/log/cron]` to `[/something/else]`.
- **Option 2:** Delete the agent state file after stopping the service.

  ```
  sudo service awslogs stop
  sudo rm /var/lib/awslogs/agent-state
  sudo service awslogs start
  ```

Please note that Option 2 may initially cause duplicate logs to be pushed to CloudWatch as a new state file is created.